# A keystore that can be used to store MongoDB encryption keys

Tags: mongodb, encryption, activemq-classic, keystore

Is there any Keystore which I can use to store MongoDB encryption keys?
Also is there any way to key rotation policy which can support both ActiveMQ and MongoDB?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB supports KMIP, so any KMIP-compliant key store will do. Vendors such as Townsend Security and SafeNet sell KMIP-compliant key stores.

Here's MongoDB's documentation about how to configure a KMIP-compliant key store: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#key-manager

As far as I can tell, ActiveMQ doesn't support KMIP or external key management.